# Printing star pattern starting from +7 on each line

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to print 8 lines where each line is incremented by 7 stars, so I will end up getting 56 stars on the last line.

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
        System.out.println();
    num += 7;
    }
```

I am ending up with 7 lines instead of 8 and thus I get 49 stars

What I expect is:

```
*******
**************
*********************
****************************
***********************************
******************************************
*************************************************
********************************************************
```

Comment: What do you think `int num = 0;` does?

Comment: change int num = 0; to int num = 7;

Comment: It start by being 0 and then 7 is added to it each i.

Comment: if you want so, change i < 8 to i < 9

Comment: `for (int i = 7; i <= 56; i += 7) System.out.println("*".repeat(i));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `num`, I would suggest you initialize `i` to `1` and use `i * 7`. Like,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i * 7; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which should do exactly what you want (and be more understandable too).

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a new iteration changing the first `for` condition to `i <= 8`, or make the first iteration actually print something, like this `int num = 7;`

Answer (score 0):

you may have to initialize `num as num=7` instead `num=0` , then you will get 8 lines.